# What is the onUI5Init global event

Tags: sapui5

Recently I came across the [following JSBin](https://jsbin.com/wihiwuw/edit?html,js,output). In the 'JavaScript' section, one can notice the initialization happening inside a global `onUI5Init` listener. This surprised me a bit, because all the demos I've seen use `sap.ui.getCore().attachInit` or otherwise `attachInit` call to the core. Moreover, there seems to be no official documentation on this event.

What does this approach do, does it execute before `attachInit` or does it have any advantages over `attachInit`? Is there some documentation I'm missing?

Any info is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] there seems to be no official documentation on this event.

You won't find "onUI5Init" anywhere in the doc because I named it. :) In the HTML panel of that JSBin sample, you can see that `"onUI5Init"` is assigned to `data-sap-ui-oninit`.

More information about `data-sap-ui-oninit` and its benefits are described in the topic *[Initialization Process](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/91f2c9076f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070#loio91f2c9076f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070)*.

See also the type description of `oninit` in *[Configuration Options and URL Parameters](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/91f2d03b6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070)* which is currently:

> Type: *code* | *string*
>
> Default value: `undefined`
>
> This configuration setting defines code that has to be executed after
> the initialization.
>
> If you define a string, this can be a reference to a function or a
> name of a module. Functions are resolved from the global namespace
> (like `"myapp.initFunction"`). Modules are indicated by the prefix
> module: (like `"module:myapp/main/Module"`). The module will be loaded
> and executed after the initialization.
>
> With `sap.ui.getCore().attachInit()` multiple handlers can be attached.
>
> The `onInit` callbacks are executed in the following order:
>
> 1. [`onInit` function/module](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/91f1f4536f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html)
> 2. [`sap.ui.getCore().attachInit`](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/91f2c9076f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html#loio91f2c9076f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070)